# Building a neighbor query based on another layer's qualities

Tags: postgresql, postgis, nearest-neighbor

I am working with PostGIS and PostgreSQL. I have 2 layers of data.

- A layer with polygons with some details attached to it i.e. table
  `polygons` with fields `id`, `quality` and `geom` (geometry shape).
- Another, a layer with
  points: a table `points` with fields `id` and `geom` (geometry shape).

For each point (example point marked yellow), I would like to find the nearest point which shows a strong characteristic but this is within a range (also yellow).
To get this quality, I have to look at the details of polygons surrounding the points under investigation (green).

```
SELECT pt1.id, pt2.id, p.id, sum(p.quality) as quality_total
FROM polygons p, points pt1, points pt2
WHERE ST_DWithin(pt1.geom, pt2.geom, 100) --points maximum 100 units away from each other
  AND ST_DWithin(p.geom, pt2.geom, 10) --polygons maximum 10 units away from point pt2
  AND (pt1.id = 1 OR pt1.id = 2) --specific points
GROUP BY quality, pt1.id, pt2.id, p.id
```

Above is my attempt so far. As you can see it is for only specific points. I was hoping the output would be for all points, like:

> `pt1.id`, `pt2.id`, `sum(p.quality)`

to mean that `pt1.id` is a point, `pt2.id` is the point nearest to pt1 (exhibiting a quality) and `sum(p.quality)` is the sum of the quality of all the polygons in pt2's range. I am at a loss how to continue building the query. I would appreciate any help. I suppose this is a form of clustering problem but I am not so educated here.

[image: Image complementing the explanation of my problem]

Comment: *For each point (example point marked yellow), I would like to find the nearest point which shows a strong characteristic* -- but you actually select multiple, not just the *nearest*. Is that intended? Also: what about points, which have no other points inside this yellow circle?

Comment: (You most probably just need `GROUP BY pt1.id, pt2.id` and leave out `p.id` from the `SELECT` list.)

Comment: For each point (e.g. point I selected with smaller yellow radius), I want to investigate nearby points within a radius/range(i.e. the larger yellow radius) and from that select the point in the range with highest `quality`... now at the end of the day I want this for all points in my data.